# Browser not Reading client certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, smartcard

I am trying to read a certificate using the following code

```
if (Page.Request.ClientCertificate.IsPresent)
{
    HttpClientCertificate cs = Request.ClientCertificate;
    string entireSubjectLine = cs.Subject.ToString();

    if (entireSubjectLine != "")
    {
        lblResponse.Text = entireSubjectLine;
    }
    else
    {
        lblResponse.Text = "No Data";
    }
}
```

This line - `if (Page.Request.ClientCertificate.IsPresent)` is returning **false**, means certificate is not being read. How to achieve it?

Comment: Are you accepting the ClientCertificate in IIS?

Comment: I did not do anything with IIS

Comment: If you did not modify IIS to accept client certificates, why do you expect this to work?

Comment: Because I have no Idea about IIS need to configure for this  :) Thank you for the tip

Comment: I am using visual studio and I dont know how to configure it. Can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you configure IIS to accept certificates:

[image: ssl settigns]

[image: accept client certificates]

This seems to make your site ask for certificates though, even if you use `Accept` and not `Require`.

Not sure if you want that.

This is for IIS. For IIS Express you can see here: https://improveandrepeat.com/2017/07/how-to-configure-iis-express-to-accept-ssl-client-certificates/